# Adding an image to a sharepoint theme

Tags: css, sharepoint

I'm trying to add a bottom banner image to our sharepoint site without editing the masterpage files.

Is this possible?

Edit:
The image should appear on all pages with the relevant theme.

Cheers,
-Jeremiah Tantongco

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't want the image on all pages? You could use an Image Web Part or Content Editor Web Part and add the images using those standard web parts.

Comment: Yes and no. They want the bottom banner as part of the website on all pages with the relevant theme.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the theme.css file in your C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extentions\12\TEMPLATES\THEMES\*themeName*

Put any images in the same folder and referer it as url('image.jpg') in the CSS, do not use / or ../ etc.

Save the file, apply a different theme to your site, recycle the application pool then apply the customized theme back. Complicated, yes I know. Keep in mind that the theme is now changed to everyone using it and will be changed when applied in the future.

If you want to find other ways to customize the site, check [this post I made a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744803/customising-sharepoint-site-design/1748382#1748382)